# Camera feature on UWP

Tags: camera, uwp

I am a student that is currently developing an UWP application. And I am trying to build a camera feature within my program. I have tested out this set of sample codes from Microsoft

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit

But I want to modify a little from the codes.

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

1. I wish to have a **preview screen** to show the user the photo their have taken and if they are not satisfied with it they can retake it. I am not very sure how to show a preview of the photo taken.
2. I do not wish to save the photo on my local storage, but instead, allow the user to **send the photo** they have taken to their **email** by typing in their email address. The main question will be, do I have to store the picture somewhere in order to send them out?

Comment: For #1, I have a written a  [working sample](https://github.com/kennyzx/UWPBank/blob/master/UWPBank/MediaPage.xaml.cs). For #2, it depends on which library you use to send the mail. You need to provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you already have the hard part figured out. Let me answer with some advice: save the file to a local folder. You can easily save the file to the Temp folder. It costs you nothing, and you don't balloon your memory footprint while you are at it. When the user wants to send, you can send it from the folder - and that is easy. Don't make things harder on yourself with difficult requirements that don't do anything but add complexity and fragility to your app. I hoe this makes sense, please take it with the utmost respect.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the advice.... however, is it possible for me to not storage the file to a local folder? Because is actually a kiosk system that is gonna be implemented on a common machine, and I dont want to storage the pictures of the users, but to send them the photo via email.